# How to execute 'source' in side shell script via ansible

Tags: shell, ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a shell script say `test.sh`, which I am able to invoke with `command` and `shell` module in ansible both. However `test.sh` is calling another shell script internally in `source ../properties/Main.sh` given fashion.

I am trying to trying to execute test.sh with ansible however, execution halts with `"No such file or directory"` Error as source is internal shell command.

test.sh looks like this

```
#/bin/bash

free -m

#echo $PWD
source ../Properties/Main.sh
#
#Remaining Part of the Script
```

Any help would be appreciated.

To clarify further, if you think `Main.sh` is not located in correct path, hence 
I am getting `file not found` Error, then you are missing the point. `Automation_v1` dir mentioned in below comments contains many directories to organize the scripts.

Comment: You have a commented-out `echo $PWD` there.  What does that show if you uncomment it?

Comment: @larsks: this is what i can see  `+ echo /tmp/Automation_v1/T1` after un-commenting  `echo $PWD` and executing shell script. and this this is my Current working Dir

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,

Providing Absolute path instead of relative path to `source` the `Main.sh` is the key.